# Creating a pure MSIL assembly from a C++/CLI project?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, clr

I am trying to create a pure MSIL assembly from a C++/CLI project using /clr:pure and /clrimagetype:pure flags, however, the output assembly specifically targets x86.

Am I missing anything that might be preventing my project to be compiled as MSIL only?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create an **AnyCPU** dll with **C++/CLI**, but in the simplest case, you will not be able to use MFC, ATL or the CRT. However, if you just want to write pure managed .NET code in C++/CLI, including managed pointers (which `/clr:safe` does not allow), and get the more elaborate code optimization of the C++/CLI compiler, read on:

1. For best results, start with a fresh project from the managed class library project template. Set the C++/CLI project properties for the DLL class library to `/clr:pure`. This is on the `Configuration Properties` page in Visual Studio 2010.
2. On the C/C++ panel, set `Omit Default Library Name` to `Yes /Zl`
3. For the linker, disable `Incremental Linking` and `Link Library Dependencies`
4. On the linker's "Advanced" page, I set the Target Machine to `Not Set` and the CLR Image Type to `Force Pure IL Image /CLRIMAGETYPE:PURE`, but some of these aparently settings aren't honored, since the 32BIT+ flag is still set by the linker in the PE32 header.
5. Therefore, add a `corflags` step to your build. The best way to do this is to exit Visual Studio and edit your vcxproj file with a text editor. At the bottom of the file, add:

   ```
       <!-- at the bottom of the file... -->
       <Target Name="AfterBuild">
           <Exec Command="corflags $(TargetPath) /32BIT-" />
       </Target>
   </Project>
   ```

   This runs the `corflags` tool to turn off the 32BIT flag in your DLL. Make sure that the `corflags.exe` tool is available in your path.
6. Finally, add a stub entry to your C++/CLI source file. This is the module static constructor. What worked for me is to place the following outside of any namespace:

   ```
   #pragma warning(disable:4483)
   void __clrcall __identifier(".cctor")() { }
   ```

That's it, you can now build the **AnyCPU** dll; it is pure `MSIL` by virtue of the 'pure' settings, and it will load either as **x64** or **x86** thanks to the `corflags` adjustment. It is up to you to avoid using any incompatible features, such as Interop, at runtime. However--and this is the difference versus just trivially using `/clr:safe` mode (which also produces an AnyCPU library)--you *can* use unsafe managed pointers to access managed value types.

---

[edit:] To elaborate on Ben Voight's comment, one thing that *won't* work in this type of **C++/CLI AnyCPU** dll is the use of C/C++ initialization syntax to initialize *unmanaged* (i.e. native), static primitives, structs, (or arrays):

```
static int my_arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

The linker issues a warning to this effect, `warning LNK4210: .CRTMA section exists; there may be unhandled static initializers or terminators`. You can, however, declare them, initialize them yourself, and use them--that is, take their addresses--and read/write them from managed code (if you want to declare such an array as `const`, then you'll have to provide empty braces `{ }` for an initializer and cast a pointer to `volatile` to initialize it.):

```
static int my_arr[3];
```

Ironically, one way to initialize these native static resources or tables is to copy them, during the module constructor or class static constructor, from a managed variable or resource.

Why bother with native statics, you ask? Because they can be quickly accessed without pinning. One nice thing **C++/CLI** still does for you here is to silently create a managed value-type (struct) to overlay each of your native statics, so that the IL code can get at them directly with IL pointers, thus keeping the assembly **/pure**.

[edit: corrected mis-statement regarding "native" pointers in an AnyCPU assembly]
[edit: clarify: 'unsafe' C# code in pure assembly uses *managed* pointers via IL instructions such as ldloca, etc.]

Comment: I should also acknowledge a Kornél Pál who is credited with discovering how to craft the module constructor stub.

Comment: You should note that this will break any global objects you might have had, since you're removing the CRT initialization code which constructs them.

Comment: @BenVoight: good point, and certainly true. I think I wouldn't mess with the technique described above if your module has anything to do with CRT or MFC. Rather, this is a way to access get access to the C++/CLI optimizing IL generator--and use unsafe constructs with it--only for pure .NET modules.

Comment: Do you also know a way to get rid of the reference to "Microsoft.VisualC" assembly?

Comment: It seems that this module constructor stub will also break all virtual method calls since CRT also initializes vtables. Anybody knows how to deal with it?

Comment: Thanks! This was super helpful. Any idea why arrays of pointers don't seem to work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51181173/array-of-pointers-in-c-cli-msil-assembly

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Visual Studio, you should be able to set the Target Machine project property under the Linker -> Advanced settings.

If what you are looking for is to compile your C++/CLI project as "Any CPU", then you need to compile in /clr:safe and /clrimagetype:safe.  See the following link for more information:

http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/660475-any-cpu-build-c-cli